# Inner product on the ring of representations of symmetric groups

Tags: representation-theory

I would like to ask what the euclidean inner product, defined on the ring of representations of $S_n$ is but first I am describing briefly the construction.
Let $G$ be a group, then $\mathrm{Irrep}(G)$ is the set of isomorphism classes of all irreducible representations. Consider a free abelian group, whose generators are elements of $\mathrm{Irrep}(G)$. It also can be defined as a group generated by classes of arbitrary finite dimensional representations (if $U$ is a representations, then $[U]$ is the corresponding class of isomorphic $G$-modules), but we then would need to identify $[U\bigoplus V]$ with $[U]+[V]$. So, we've built a $\mathbb{Z}$-molule $\mathcal{R}_G$ and now for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we introduce $\mathcal{R}_n$ for the ring $\mathcal{R}_{S_n}$ of representations of the symmetric group $S_n$.
Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the sum $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{R}_n$. It is possible to endow $\mathcal{R}$ with a structure of a graded ring as follows: given to representations $U$ and $V$ of $S_n$ and $S_k$ respectively, we embed $S_n\times S_k$ into $S_{k+n}$ naturally and define the product of classes $[U][V]=[\mathrm{Ind}_{S_k\times S_n}^{S_{k+n}}U\boxtimes V]$. It also can be easily proved that $\mathcal{R}$ is a commutative (graded) ring. 
However I am confused with a suggestion to endow $\mathcal{R}$ with a *euclidean inner product such that the classes $[S^{\lambda}]$ of irreducible representations form an orthonormal base*! How to do that?! What I mean is that $\mathcal{R}$ is just a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but not a vector space! I suppose the author forgets to say that we consider $\mathcal{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, doesn't he?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is probably just being poetic, using "Euclidean inner product" to describe a bilinear form that functions like the dot product when elements are represented as coordinate vectors with respect to some $\Bbb Z$-basis. Although sometimes one extends the scalars of the representation ring up, so it is possible. With more context, maybe a link or citation, we could tell more definitively.

This happens in other contexts too. For instance, the map $(x,y)\mapsto {\rm tr}_{L/K}(xy)$ can be intuitively considered a kind of inner product, where $L/K$ is a field extension, even without $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ present.